# Link validator incorrectly marks ampersands as broken links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, character-escaping, link-validator

We just got crawled for broken links for the first time, and many of the links are of the format

```
http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&amp;nodeId=1406&amp;dDocName=en553673
//        Note the &amp; --------------------------------------^^^^^  ---------^^^^^
```

These links are not broken, the actual question source contains a literal ampersand character:

```
http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en553673
//         Not broken  ----------------------------------------^   --------^
```

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saziw.png) of the broken links page and [the](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18379) [associated](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16021) [posts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/4214) with working links for examples.  I have yet to find a post where the URL incorrectly contained the characters `&amp;`, so I've started ignoring any URLs where I see this string.

Comment: confirmed something odd is going on, working on a fix now